# TSQL DateTime Comparison

Tags: t-sql

What I am trying to do is get a result from sql where the dates are in a certain range but its not working correctly, here is my query.

```
DECLARE @CurrDate DATETIME
SET @CurrDate = GETDATE()
SELECT dbo.ProductDetails.PartnerID
      ,dbo.ProductDetails.ProductID
      ,dbo.Products.ProductName
      ,StartDate
      ,EndDate
FROM dbo.ProductDetails
    INNER JOIN dbo.Products
        ON dbo.ProductDetails.ProductID = dbo.Products.ProductID
WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),StartDate,111) <= @CurrDate
  AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),EndDate,  111) >= @CurrDate
```

but when the `Enddate = @CurrDate` the row does not show, but if i make that date just one day higher it gets displayed. Am i doing anything wrong? Any advice will do, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want only DATE comparison, without time use the

```
cast(CONVERT(varchar, StartDate, 112) as datetime)
```

Comment: but that's not taking into account that `GetDate()` is also delivering a time, right? you'd have to do the same conversion there as well...

Comment: Yes i did that conversion there aswell and it is working now.
Thanks!

Comment: If using SQL 2008, can do:  `Cast(StartDate as Date)`

Answer (score 5):

`GetDate()` returns **date and time**, while your conversion to varchar strips away the time part (I'm suspecting that's all it's actually supposed to do). So you would need to do the same conversion for `@CurrDate`.

If what you want is to simply consider the date only (ignoring the time part), you could use `DATEDIFF` instead of converting to varchar (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms189794.aspx)); example:

```
DECLARE @CurrDate DATETIME
SET @CurrDate = GETDATE()
SELECT dbo.ProductDetails.PartnerID, dbo.ProductDetails.ProductID, 
         dbo.Products.ProductName , StartDate, EndDate
    FROM dbo.ProductDetails INNER JOIN
         dbo.Products ON dbo.ProductDetails.ProductID = dbo.Products.ProductID
    -- where StartDate is on the same day or before CurrDate:
    WHERE DATEDIFF(day, StartDate, @CurrDate) >= 0 AND
    -- and where EndDate is on the same day or after CurrDate:
          DATEDIFF(day, EndDate, @CurrDate)   <= 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I am quite sure that the comparison takes into account the time as well as the date, in which case if the dates are the same but the current time is greater than the time being compared to you won't get that row as a result.

So, what you need to do is just extract the date part and compare those.

Answer (score 1):

GETDATE() gives you date and time 
if yours column have only date
then

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),StartDate,111) <= @CurrDate
```

can give you unexpected result

remember 
19.12.2011 14:41 > 19.12.2011 00:00

Comment: Ok so i should be setting @CurrDate to Date only?
Makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL 2008 or later, and wanting to compare only the date, not the time, you can also do:

```
Cast(StartDate as Date)
```

(This avoids having to convert to a string.)